# How to match the password in maatwebsite excel when file is password protected?

Tags: php, laravel, phpexcel, maatwebsite-excel

I have  imported password protected excel file in laravel .xls but i am getting balnk page.

```
$path = $request->file->getRealPath();
$data = Excel::load($path, function ($reader) {
                })->get();
Return in page:-
  Maatwebsite\Excel\Collections\SheetCollection Object ( [title:protected] => [items:protected] => Array ( ) )
```

Any code where i got hash data.
Any help could be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the password?

Comment: yes! I have password but i want to match password .

Comment: What do you mean by _match password?_

Comment: Do have any code to check the excel file is protected or not in laravel? and if file is password protected then i want to verify the password in the uploading time.

Comment: If you manually open the file in excel and then remove the password and try loading it in Laravel will it work?

Comment: That i know but i want to read/open excel file with password protected and access the data.

Comment: Have you read https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/398#issuecomment-94509469

Comment: @Thomas  i need to retrive password through excel file  is any method to get password when i uploading password protected excel file? In this link only i get set password.